# Width of cell ignored

Tags: html, css

I have looked for many posts but I could not find an answer that suits this problem. I have tried with `table-layout:fixed`, changing widths to extreme values but the attribute `width` is still being ignored. Here is my code:

```
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed; border: 1pt solid black; 
              border-collapse: collapse;" border cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <th align=center colspan="4" 
        style="width:100%; color:white; background-color:#475678; font-weight:bold;">
        Oferta de traducción para: ' . $cliente . '
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-right:1pt solid black; width:10%;">Fecha</td>
    <td align=center style="border-right:1pt solid black; width:10%;">Fecha</td>
    <td style="border-right:1pt solid black; width:40%;"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;">Fecha</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: **Just a pointer:** You shouldn't style inline you should always make an id or a class within your css file.

Comment: In what sense is it ignored? Also the sum of your cell widths does not add up to 100%. I'm not sure what the specified behaviour is for that but you should fix that and check again.

Comment: "tried changing widths to extreme values" this is definitely not a good idea. What about totalling 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `table-layout: fixed` is the one that ignores your widths.

from MDN [HTML table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) says like this about the table-layout: fixed,

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue was using `table-layout: fixed;`

Here is my retake on it.

Within the `<style>` you should put this into your css but assign an id or class to it if you're using tables elsewhere that are different:

```css
table {
        width: 100%;
        border:1pt solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table td {
        width:25%;
        border-right: 1pt solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    table th {
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        background: #475678;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th align=center colspan="4">Oferta de traducción para: ' . $cliente . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Fecha</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to keep your CSS in the actual code, just remove the `table-layout` from `<table>` styling.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove `table-layout:fixed;` and it will work.